# How to use Windows Phone camera burst mode

Tags: windows-phone-7, camera

I am following this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202956.aspx) to create a camera application for windows phone. I am wondering is there any way that I can create a camera burst mode?

I have tried to use DispatchTimer, and set DispatchTimer.Interval equals to TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50), which means camera takes 20 frames per second, unfortunatlly it failed.

Can anyone give me a direction or code example? Thanks

Comment: Why not just switch to video mode? Taking 20 full-size frames per seconds would depend ENTIRELY on how much horsepower the camera's chip has to convert a full-frame image -> jpg in a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: I am trying to create a burst mode.

Comment: Hi Alex, did you solve this problem? I am also running into similar issues. Please post a solution to this page if you have found the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I myself ran into that kind of problem i.e. creating a burst mode application. I did a lot of research then i found out that with windows phone 8 sdk you can process and save individual frames, so i thought why not use the individual frames as burst photo shoot. find out more details on these links

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662940%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662939%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a timer you have to capture the 2nd pictue after (!) capturing the first one. This is because the capturing time depends on various factor like resolution, phone model, background tasks, etc. and is difficult to predict. Another solution could be to set the timer to a high interval (a second or even more) but this is not a real burst mode anymore.